# Should we merge [chronology] and [chronological-order]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a [chronology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) tag with 19 questions and a [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order) tag with 9 questions. They seem to be used in the same way. (A couple [chronology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) questions should perhaps be retagged [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order).)

Should we merge and synonymize these tags?

Comment: Ugh, this looks like another tagging quagmire. I'm digging in deep to find out how these tags are (or should be) used.

Comment: [tag:lineage] and [tag:genealogy] were much easier to sort out. Merged and synonymised.

Comment: Thanks - I just merged them, and also improved the tag wiki for [tag:sentience] (tag wiki excerpts shouldn't be just definitions). And I did create a synonym, since evidently "popping up when you start typing 'sentien...'" wasn't enough to stop both tags from being created in the first place! (IMO, [tag:sentience] is a kinda useless tag, but I don't care enough to start a meta on that.)

Comment: This question just got bumped because you haven't upvoted or accepted my answer :-)

Comment: Not just 'by default', but because I actually did all the necessary edits to, as they say, *make it so*. Just forgot to edit my answer to say so, which I've now done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, here are the usage patterns of these tags:

1. [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order)

   This is used similarly to [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order): for questions asking about **the chronological order of certain SFF works in the same series**. For example, [What is the chronological order of the novels in Asimov's Foundation series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-is-the-chronological-order-of-the-novels-in-asimovs-foundation-series) and [What is the chronological order of Warcraft canon media?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117748/what-is-the-chronological-order-of-warcraft-canon-media)

   <strike>There are only two exceptions to this usage guidance:</strike>

   - [When do we first hear the name "Anakin"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108553/when-do-we-first-hear-the-name-anakin)
   - [Is there a way to bypass the paradox system with a Time Turner in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103916/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-the-paradox-system-with-a-time-turner-in-harry-potter)

   I can't see why either of these questions have the [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order) tag, and propose that we remove it. The first one could arguably be tagged [chronology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) instead (see below).
2. [chronology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology)

   Questions with this tag generally seem to be about **the chronology of specific in-universe events**, i.e. what order things happened in within SFF works. For example, [Which of these Enderverse characters died first?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44933/which-of-these-enderverse-characters-died-first) and [Chronologically, when does the Death Star scene of Revenge of the Sith take place?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124438/chronologically-when-does-the-death-star-scene-of-revenge-of-the-sith-take-plac)

   <strike>However, there are also several questions with this tag which are asking about the order of works in the same series. IMO, four of these should be retagged [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order) and four should be retagged [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order):</strike>

   - [What is the order/timeline for Iain M. Banks "Culture" novels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-the-order-timeline-for-iain-m-banks-culture-novels) [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order)
   - [Is there an "official"-ish complete chronological order for Star Wars C-canon material (books+comics+games)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/is-there-an-official-ish-complete-chronological-order-for-star-wars-c-canon-ma) [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order)
   - [X-Men Story/Chronology 2000 - 2010](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4396/x-men-story-chronology-2000-2010) [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order)
   - [What is the chronology of the Gundam series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/what-is-the-chronology-of-the-gundam-series) [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order)
   - [Chronology of Ray Bradbury's Martian short stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36332/chronology-of-ray-bradburys-martian-short-stories) [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order)
   - [What is the chronological order for the Star Trek series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/what-is-the-chronological-order-for-the-star-trek-series) [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order)
   - [James Blish, Cities in Flight series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65316/james-blish-cities-in-flight-series) [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order)
   - [X-men Reading Order EDIT](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87301/x-men-reading-order-edit) [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order)

Once again, we have 10 questions to be retagged, which should be few enough to do over the course of a day or two without causing too much annoyance. Standard disclaimers apply: **please don't do too many at once**, as we don't want to flood the front page with old questions bumped by tag edits, especially relatively minor tag edits like this. A useful rule of thumb is to ensure that at most 5 of the top 15 questions on the front page of the site were last edited by you.

Also, the tag wikis for [chronology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology), [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order), and [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) should be rewritten to reflect the actual usage of these tags. Each tag should have a clear and unambiguous meaning which is summarised concisely and accurately in the tag wiki excerpt.

**EDIT:** all required editing of posts and tag wikis has been done. This issue is now solved.

Comment: I just retagged the two [tag:chronological-order] questions that didn't fit the main usage of the tag.

Comment: It’s never as simple as I think...

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess I could be helping with the retagging. But there are so many tags in disarray... Spend 30 seconds looking at that SVG tag map and you'll find something amiss, no matter where you look.

Comment: @anaranjada I've nearly finished the retagging now. Would appreciate if you could fix the tag wikis though - you have a knack for writing those :-)

Comment: OK, I'll update the tag wikis tonight or tomorrow. I'm the [most prolific tag wiki excerpt editor](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/467755/top-editors-by-type-of-edit?EditTypes=4) on the site now. Still not the [top edit suggester](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/475597/top-edit-suggesters) though.

Comment: I proposed edits to all three tag wikis. I’m logging off for the night, so you can check my [recent edit suggestions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/36115/anaranjada?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to see if they went through.

Comment: @anaranjada - I think we need some sort of site consensus before we say "Here's what this tag means".   I don't see any reason to assume that chronology and chronological order are anything more than synonyms.

Comment: @WadCheber Doesn't "how the tags have actually been used for the last 5 years" count as site consensus on what they mean? If you read my answer here, I analysed both tags thoroughly and discovered that although on first sight they appear to be synonymous, they are in fact used differently.

Comment: @WadCheber I wouldn’t object to them being made synonyms, and that’s what I was asking for in this question. But I try to describe current usage in the tag wikis, so I went with the distinct usage as described by Rand. It might be too fine a distinction, but nobody is interested in talking about tags during the Scope Wars.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I don't know if a total of ~25 questions is proof of real usage differences or just coincidence

Comment: @WadCheber You and Jonah have mentioned that you think the tag wikis could still use improvement. Feel free to edit them, or retag everything, or whatever you want to do. Anything is fine with me.